# How to properly use DisposableEffect in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to listen for **sensor data** in a `@Composable` and cancel listening for sensor data when returning to the previous interface.

So I wrote the following code:

```kotlin
PresetsList {
  navigator.navigate(
    PresetsEditorDestination(
      orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE,
      presetsModel = it
    )
  )
}
```

`PresetsList` contains multiple jumpable `PresetsEditor` interfaces

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalLifecycleComposeApi::class)
@Destination
@Composable
fun PresetsEditor(
  orientation: Int,
  presetsModel: PresetsModel,
  viewModel: EditorViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
  val context = LocalContext.current
  val systemUiController = LocalSystemUiController.current
  val dialogState by viewModel.dialogState.collectAsState()
  val steeringValue by viewModel.sensorFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

  systemUiController.systemBarsBehavior =
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE

  DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    
    // Force this @Composable to be landscape and hide the statusBar.

    val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@DisposableEffect onDispose {}
    val originalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
    activity.requestedOrientation = orientation
    systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = false

    onDispose {
      activity.requestedOrientation = originalOrientation
      systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = true
      viewModel.stopListeningSensor() // stop listening sensor.
    }
  }

  println("steeringValue: $steeringValue")

  EditorContent(
    presetsModel, 
    dialogState, 
    viewModel::onClickLabel, 
    viewModel::onDismissRequest
  )
}
```

`viewModel.kt`

```
@HiltViewModel
class EditorViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val sensor: AbstractSensor
) : ViewModel(){

  private val _sensorFlow = MutableStateFlow(0f)
  val sensorFlow = _sensorFlow.asStateFlow()

  init {
    sensor.startListening()
    sensor.setOnSensorValuesChangedListener {
      _sensorFlow.value = it
    }
  }
}
```

But I encountered a problem. When I jump to this `@Composable` from other interfaces, the code in my `onDispose` will run the `stopListeningSensor` method once, which will cause my sensor data to end shortly after I start listening. So I'm a little lost on how to use `DisposableEffect` to solve this problem.

Comment: It is being called because the Composable is being destroyed. Post the Composable containing this peice of code.

Comment: Fascinating... `PresetsList` itself is a Composable, that expects a lambda body seemingly exposing a Composable scope, and you're calling a method in there called `navigate`, **which in turn takes a Composable** as an argument!? Ha, sir/lady your architecture choices are beyond Earth's natural being. You're in a celestial `State`.

Comment: Also, you didn't post where the `PresetsEditor` Composable is being called in the first place. That was the main request.

Comment: You may have misunderstood me, PresetsList is a LazyColumn, which calls back the click event of each item in it, and the parameter in the navigate you mentioned is a @Composable just because I used the compose-destination library.

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper According to the non-use of this library In practice, you can understand that PresetsEditor is initially placed in NavHost, and the callback of PresetsList executes `navigator.navite("presetsEditor", model = xxx)` instead of taking @Composable as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the value of `steeringValue` inside your Composable, which is a value bound to change, as you reveal. What's the invisible issue here? Obviously the change in the value will trigger a recomposition leading to `onDispose` being called, which is the expected behaviour. If all you want is to run a codeblock when the Composable goes out-of-composition, then it would be easier to place that codeblock at the place where you make the navigation call. It might be a little risky to place it within the Composable without proper knowledge and handling of scopes and side-effects. One way I see to add it within the Composable while taking care of all of that, is to use the `BackHandler` Composable. It receives a lambda that would only be executed when the user presses the back button.

`BackHandler { ... }`

Move the `onDispose logic to one of these blocks, and it should work.

There's no way to know when a Composable goes *out-of-composition*, so you're only bet is to place the logic in a custom-handled event, like the back press, or when the app is pushed to the background, using `onStop`, or to be the most accurate, place the call at the place where you call the navigation method, which is the architecture most normal developers would go with. You probably won't be able to perform the latter since you're using an out-of-earth library for navigation, so... Yeah, good luck to you sir/lady.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your answer, I made some mistakes, the details are in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't describe my problem clearly, although I wrote comments in the code. My problem is jumping from a normal @Composable (in portrait) to a @Composable in landscape and after the jump starts listening for sensor data.

The reason why `onDispose` is triggered once when entering @Composable is actually because `configuration` is changed, and the life cycle of Activity is executed once `ON_STOP` (because of the change of screen orientation)

The solution is also simple: remove the init block in my viewModel as it doesn't need such a long life cycle (eg when the app is in the background, no need to listen for sensor data), and start listening for sensor data in the `DisposableEffect` block.

```kotlin
val activity = LocalContext.current as MainActivity

DisposableEffect(Unit) {

  // Force this @Composable to be landscape and hide the statusBar.
  val originalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
  activity.requestedOrientation = orientation
  systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = false

  viewModel.startListeningSensor()

  onDispose {
    activity.requestedOrientation = originalOrientation
    systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = true
    viewModel.stopListeningSensor() // stop listening sensor.
  }
}
```

Finally, I'd like to say to Richard Onslow Roper that the navigation library I'm using is fine, it's just that I stupidly didn't think that the lifecycle caused by screen changes affects the DisposableEffect (it does exactly what Richard Onslow Roper said in the first comment, My @Composable is destroyed) and doesn't clearly describe what's going on in my code.